# Removing leading and trailing quotation marks in Google Sheets / Apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am writing a script to populate a cell with some information for a mailer. I'm fairly new to this, so am guessing the coding isn't perfect.  However, all I really need to achieve is to get a block of text - and it's pretty much there.

**The problem is, that when it returns the text it adds a qutoation at start and at the end.**

Can someone let me know how to return the text without this.

```
function MailerText(strMailer, strName) {
  
  if (strMailer === undefined || strMailer === "Ignore") {return ""};
  
  let  varBody
  let  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Actions");

  
  if (strMailer == 'A Style English') {varBody = formS.getRange('C1').getValue(); varSalutation = formS.getRange('B1').getValue();}
  else if (strMailer == 'A Style German - Female') {varBody = formS.getRange('C2').getValue(); varSalutation = formS.getRange('B2').getValue();};
  
  if (varBody == undefined) {return ""};
  return varSalutation + ' ' + strName + ',' + "\n" + "\n" + varBody; 

}
```

As requested, here are a few screen shots of the issue:

Image 1: The function call from the cell

Image 2: How it looks in Sheets after the function call

Image 3: What you get when you copy/paste the text into something.

[image: The function call from the cell]

[image: How it looks in Sheets]

[image: When you copy the cell and paste it into something, you have the quotation marks]

Comment: Can you show a screen capture of where the quotes show up.  There is nothing in your script that would include quotes. `varSalutation` is simply a concatination of strings.  And the use of single quotes or double quotes in the concatination only provide deliniation of a portion of the string but are not included in it.

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: Try temporary to remove the `\n` from the return: `return varSalutation + ' ' + strName + ',' + varBody`

Comment: I think the problem is SpreadsheetApp (and Excel) adds quotemarks around of contents of the cell as it puts in clipboard if there are `\n` inside the cell. To distinguish the `\n` between rows. If you need multiline text in clipboard you have to figure out a workaround. For example you could spread the text over several cells, one cell = one line (paragraph) of the text, to avoid to add '\n' inside a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case after researching for a while it seems that whenever Sheets detects that there are special characters or line breaks you will get the quotation marks added when the text is copied, there is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886559/why-does-copying-multi-row-text-from-google-sheets-to-the-instagram-caption-box) about this behavior and it contains a good workaround if you don't mind copying  the text to a different cell then you can try this formula on another cell:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C609,char(10),char(13))
```

This would basically copy the text without the special characters on it and when copy/pasted from the cell where the formula is added then you will see that the quotations will no longer be there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of your help.  The final SUBSTITUTE command did the trick perfectly.  I enclosed that with a TRIM(...) function and it is perfect.  Much appreciated.