# Hidden apostrophes when importing text file with formulas to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

when importing csv file to Google Sheets, or when exporting a table from BigQuery to Google Sheets it adds hidden apostrophe (‘), i.e. single quote to all formulas, e.g. `=IMAGE()` -> `'=IMAGE()`

it seems to be a new behavior, any ideas how to import text files with formulas to Google Sheets without the single quote being automatically inserted (right now i just run Find/Replace after import but wanted to avoid that manual step if possible)

Comment: not rly an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615734/how-to-detect-a-leading-single-quote-char39-in-google-sheets) but it could help you with the detection

Comment: You may want to check this [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/35905245) related to that behavior

Comment: thanks, it says if there is a single quote it would be treated as text, but how do i avoid that single quote being automatically inserted in front of formulas in the first place (on import to google sheets)

Comment: You could try the solution posted from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886559/why-does-copying-multi-row-text-from-google-sheets-to-the-instagram-caption-box) as the issue is already being tracked through the IssueTracker a direct solution can't be provided however the workaround in that post may help.